# Unauthorizedaccessexception for a directory that the application created (IIS locked file)

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, file-io, file-permissions

I have a program where a user can upload a photo and it is stored inside the application (e.g. ~/files/ac9ff990-273c-4fda-a51a-155c54db72ab/original/photo1.jpg). Later on the user can delete the file. This works fine except that when though all the subfiles and folders are removed the told level folder (this GUID one) remains and I get an Unauthorizedaccessexception error thrown. I'm left with loads of empty folders which is really annoying when dealing with 1000s of uploads.

I can't see how it can be a permissions thing as there is nothing odd about the permissions and I get the same issue on my desktop as on the live server. I've turned indexing off and tried giving 'EVERYONE' permission without any luck and setting the folder owner to different users without any luck. (I've also not got the folder open in Windows Explorer)

I fail to see how this can be a permissions issue as .NET should use the same folder for creating it as deleting it. Any ideas?

public class FileManager
    {
        private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(FileManager));
        public enum UPLOAD_TYPE : int { ORIGINAL_FILE = 1, PROCESSED_FILE = 2, ANCILLARY_FILE = 3 }

```
    private const string userFilesFolder = "~/files/";
    private const string originalSubFolder = "original/";
    private const string processedSubFolder = "processed/";
    private const string ancillarySubFolder = "ancillary/";


    internal static void DeleteJobItemFiles(Guid jobItemId)
    {
        if (jobItemId == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ApplicationException("jobItemId is Empty");

        try
        {
            var directory = GetDirectory(jobItemId);

            string routePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(directory.AbsolutePath));
            if (Directory.Exists(routePath))
                Directory.Delete(routePath, true);
        }
        catch (HttpException exception)
        {
            throw new UploadManagerException(ERROR_CODE.HTTP_CONTEXT_NULL, exception);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new UploadManagerException(ERROR_CODE.GENERAL_FILE, exception);
        }
    }

    internal static string SaveFile(Guid jobItemId, Stream inputStream, UPLOAD_TYPE uploadType, string fileName)
    {
        if (jobItemId == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentException("jobItemId is Empty");
        if (inputStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputStream");
        if (fileName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

        if (inputStream.CanSeek)
            inputStream.Position = 0;

        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -_\\.]");
        fileName = rgx.Replace(fileName, "");
        fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "");

        var directoryPathUri = GetDirectory(jobItemId, uploadType);
        // New file Uri
        var fileUri = new Uri(directoryPathUri, fileName);


        try
        {
            string localDirectoryPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(directoryPathUri.AbsolutePath));
            string localFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fileUri.AbsolutePath));

            if (!Directory.Exists(localDirectoryPath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localDirectoryPath);

            using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(localFilePath))
            {
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[256];
                inputStream.Position = 0;
                int bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                while (bytesRead > 0);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            log.Error("Unexpected exception in FileManager.SaveFile", exception);
            throw new UploadManagerException(ERROR_CODE.FILE_SAVE, exception);
        }
        catch (HttpException exception)
        {
            throw new UploadManagerException(ERROR_CODE.HTTP_CONTEXT_NULL, exception);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new UploadManagerException(ERROR_CODE.GENERAL_FILE, exception);
        }

        var rootUri = GetDirectory();
        return VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(fileUri.AbsolutePath);
    }

    private static Uri GetDirectory()
    {
        // Root of site
        try
        {
            return new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url, HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
        }
        catch (HttpException exception)
        {
            throw new UploadManagerException(ERROR_CODE.HTTP_CONTEXT_NULL, exception);
        }
    }

    private static Uri GetDirectory(Guid jobItemId)
    {
        if (jobItemId == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentException("jobItemId is Empty");

        var rootUri = GetDirectory();
        //Folder where all files are stored
        var userFilesUri = new Uri(rootUri, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(userFilesFolder));
        //Folder for job
        return new Uri(userFilesUri, jobItemId.ToString() + "/");
    }

    private static Uri GetDirectory(Guid jobItemId, UPLOAD_TYPE uploadType)
    {
        if (jobItemId == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentException("jobItemId is Empty");

        string subFolder;
        switch (uploadType)
        {
            case UPLOAD_TYPE.ORIGINAL_FILE:
                subFolder = originalSubFolder;
                break;
            case UPLOAD_TYPE.PROCESSED_FILE:
                subFolder = processedSubFolder;
                break;
            case UPLOAD_TYPE.ANCILLARY_FILE:
                subFolder = ancillarySubFolder;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        //Folder for file
        return new Uri(GetDirectory(jobItemId), subFolder);
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT UPDATE: This seems to be caused by IIS locking files, or similar. The images I'm trying to delete are displayed on a page. When a WCF call comes in to delete the page the folders can't be deleted. If If I edit the HTML so that the images aren't displayed then the folders can be deleted. Make any sense to anyone?

Comment: I get the feeling that some unmanaged item isn't being cleaned up properly. It would help a lot if you made a much smaller app that shows the problem.

Comment: I will do that. I tried removing Directory.Delete(path, true) for a recursive function that calls file1.Delete() and dir1.Delete(). Interesting the dir1.Delete() for the original folder seemed to be ineffectual until after the guid folder had tried and failed to  delete:
/guid/original/photo1.jpg

`private static void RecursiveDelete(DirectoryInfo dirInfo) {
            foreach (var directory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
            { RecursiveDelete(directory); }
            foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
            {  file.Delete(); }
            dirInfo.Delete();
}`

Comment: My little app worked fine, suggesting that there is nothing wrong with this code. Any brainwaves on what sort of issue might exists elsewhere that could cause this?